# Identificar filas repetidas en una nueva columna

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente codigo, que crea un DF

```
#create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'points': [10, 10, 12, 12, 15, 17, 20, 20],
                   'assists': [5, 5, 7, 9, 12, 9, 6, 6]})
print(df)
```

[image: DF original]

Me interesaría añadirle una columna nueva al DF que identifique a los diferentes jugadores comparandolos por team and points y le vaya añadiendo una columna nueva con el número de jugador. Tal que obtuviese un resultado así:

[image: Df deseado]

He intentado con isin y duplicates pero no consigo nada.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

#### Agrupas según las columnas

Agrupas según las columnas poniendole index de 1 a n. Debes usar `.first()` para obtener la primera fila de la agrupación, sino te devuelve el grupo entero.

```py
# %% Create auxiliary dataframe
# Group by the two columns of interest with range() indexing, take the first element
aux=df.groupby(["team","points"],as_index=False).first()
# Filter the two columns of interest
aux=aux[["team","points"]]
# Create the new column "Jugador" the same as the index arange
aux["Jugador"]=aux.index+1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Luego unes ambas:

```py
df.merge(aux,how='left')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -2):

En la primera parte esta tu condicional, luego el nombre de la nueva columna y por ultimo el valor que quieres asignarle, para que funcione tienes que hacer todos los casos uno por uno copiando el codigo y cambiando el condicional y el valor a asignar

```
df.loc[(df["team"] == "A") & (df["points"] = 10 ), "numero de jugador(nueva columna)"] = (valor que quieres asignarle)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución. Pero tu respuesta es solo código, podrías agregar una explicación de como funciona por favor?

Comment: Puedes goglear como funciona el codigo, primera vez usando stack overflow me esta costando insertar el codigo por parte, no se si lo viste completo es una linea larga, tampoco se como agregarle espacios para que se vea completo, pero en la primera parte esta tu condicional, luego el nombre de la nueva columna y por ultimo el valor que quieres asignarle, para que funcione tienes que hacer todos los casos uno por uno copiando el codigo y cambiando el condicional y el valor a asignar

Comment: Estoy sospechando que crees que soy el autor de la pregunta. Yo te decia lo que dije para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad y el OP aprenda aun más.

Comment: _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._ Lee [answer]: el contenido esencial debe estar en la respuesta misma, por lo tanto explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código (pulsando en [edit]). Puede que para ti sea claro cómo funciona, pero para otros no. Además, evita enviar a los demás a sitios externos o a que busquen la información en otros motores de búsqueda. Recuerda que [es.so] no es un repositorio de código (no es un "cópialo, pégalo y listo"). Como ejemplo de respuesta, fíjate en la otra respuesta de esta misma pregunta.